# Using chained with cake php3

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to load data from select according to another select options data , so i have used Chained idea for that , but i'm having issues with getting the related data , I have make that at my view :

```
  echo $this->Form->input('warehouse_categories_items_id', ['options' => $warehouseCategoriesItems,'class' => 'form-control','id'=>'type']);
                                    echo $this->Form->input('warehouse_items_id', ['options' => $warehouseItems, 'class' => 'form-control','id'=>'item','data-chained'=>$query]);


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#item").chainedTo("#type");
});
```

and at my controller :

```
 $query = $this->WarehouseAddOrdersItemsForm7->find('all')
    ->contain([ 'WarehouseCategoriesItems', 'WarehouseItems' => function($q){
        return $q->where(['WarehouseItems.warehouse_categories_items_id' => 'WarehouseCategoriesItems.id']);
    }]);
$warehouseCategoriesItems = $this->WarehouseAddOrdersItemsForm7->WarehouseCategoriesItems->find('list', ['valueField' => 'category_item_name','limit' => 200]);
     $warehouseItems = $this->WarehouseAddOrdersItemsForm7->WarehouseItems->find('list', ['valueField' => 'warehouse_item_name','limit' => 200]);
```

But it's only getting my the first select option data , and not getting the second related data .

Comment: You used jquery chained that is fine. But after changing 1st dropdown, do any request sent to the server? @Dina Shaldoum

Comment: No , It's not  It's giving me the all results and that's not true , not the related values .

Comment: https://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/, this is where you will found the documentation.

Comment: The issue is that , i'm trying to get the data-chained dynamic but i can't it's back null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use cascaded select, you have 2 way:-

> 1. Local(Providing all the data to select options)
> 2. Remotely(Will request to server for option then will append/prepend the option to the select)

I am giving you the example and steps to follow for each way:-

**Locally:-(Not writing code in CakePHP so that you can understand properly)**

```
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" data-chained="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" data-chained="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" data-chained="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" data-chained="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" data-chained="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" data-chained="audi">A5</option>
</select>
```

Notice that In data-chained, you have to write the parent select value so that by selecting parent, so that it will display only relevant child options.

**Remotely/Server(If you want to use filter from server):-**

You have to request to the server through AJAX, like

```
<select id="mark" name="mark">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
<option value="">--</option>
</select>
<select id="model" name="model">
<option value="">--</option>
</select>
<select id="engine" name="engine">
<option value="">--</option>
</select>
```

1st select box with value and other with empty(Data will be bind after server response)

```
$("#series").remoteChained({
  parents : "#mark",
  url : "series/optionData"
});

$("#model").remoteChained({
  parents : "#series",
  url : "models/optionData"
});

$("#engine").remoteChained({
  parents : "#series, #model",
  url : "engines/optionData"
});
```

In your Controller's method optionData, if you have to send the data's in JSON format(Simply find the data from DB then use PHP funciton json_encode to convert the option data to JSON).

**TO CREATE data-chained ATTRIBUTE FOR THE OPTIONS, If you want local binding**
You have to create an array in your controller like this,
You can do something like this,

```
$options = [
    ['text' => 'Series-3', 'value' => 'series-3', 'data-chained' => 'bmw'],
    ['text' => 'Series-5', 'value' => 'series-5', 'data-chained' => 'bmw'],
    ['text' => 'A-3', 'value' => 'a-3', 'data-chained' => 'audi'];

echo $this->Form->select('field', $options);
```

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Can you just tell me how to put data-chained="bmw" , in cake php ?

Comment: You can do something like this,

Comment: Comment is not accepting many characters, so I have added answer for your query at the end of the answer. @Dina Shaldoum